# Initial value problem on $\mathcal{I}^-$ for Maxwell fields

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, differential-equations, classical-field-theory

In the paper "[Symplectic Geometry of Radiative Modes and Conserved Quantities at Null Infinity](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/abs/10.1098/rspa.1981.0109)" by Ashtekar and Streubel the authors state the following:

> Fix, as in § 2(a), a conformal completion $(M,g_{ab})$ of $(\hat{M},\hat{g}_{ab})$ in which $\mathcal{I}$ is divergence-free. Consider a solution $\hat{F}_{ab}$ to (2.13) [Maxwell's equations] that induces smooth initial data of compact support on any Cauchy surface in $(\hat{M},\hat{g}_{ab})$. $F_{ab}=\hat{F}_{ab}$ satisfies Maxwell's equations on $(M,g_{ab})$. **$F_{ab}$ is completely characterized by its null-datum, $\mathscr{E}_a$, the pull-back to $\mathcal{I}$ of $F_{ab}n^b$ (Penrose 1965)**.

Now my doubt is with bold sentence. It basically says that the necessary initial data on $\mathcal{I}^-$ to fully specify the electromagnetic field is $\mathscr{E}_a$ the pullback of $F_{ab}n^b$ to $\mathcal{I}^-$. If I'm not mistaken this would mean that in advanced coordinates the initial data is $\{F_{vA}\}$ where $v$ is advanced time and $x^A$ are the coordinates on the $S^2$ part of $\mathcal{I}^-$. Is that right?

I find this confusing because with spacelike Cauchy surfaces I'm used to the appropriate initial data to formulate one initial value problem is: (1) the value of the field and (2) the value of the "time derivative" of the field.

More precisely, as stated by Wald (General Relativity book), for a linear, diagonal second order hyperbolic system, for the fields $\phi_i$ the initial value formulation on the spacelike Cauchy surface $\Sigma$ is well-posed given smooth initial data $(\phi_i, n^a\nabla_a \phi_i)$.

So what about the initial value formulation of Maxwell's equations at $\mathcal{I}^-$? Why the appropriate initial data is $\mathscr{E}_a = F_{ab} n^b$? Don't we need to specify a derivative also?

Is there even a way to intuitively grasp why at $\mathcal{I}^-$ we don't need to specify the derivative and just the values of the projection onto the normal?

References to this result are really appreciated. I've tried the cited Penrose paper but unfortunatelly I'm not well acquainted yet with the spinor methods he employs and so didn't find it very readable. References to the problem without employing spinor methods are appreciated.